# How to convert 3*3 matrix to 9*3 matrix with following format using Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Anybody help me to solve the given below requirement. here need to convert from 3*3 to 9*3 matrix as given below format. Thanks.

```
    /* input int[][] intArray = {{3, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 6},{8, 7, 9}};
     * output :- int[][] dataArray = new int[9][3];
     * 
     * int[][] dataArray = [[0,0,3],[0,1,2],[0,2,1],[1,0,4],[1,1,5],[1,2,6],[2,0,8],[2,1,7],[2,2,9]];
     */

    int[][] dataArray = new int[9][3];

    for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<dataArray[0].length;j++){
    //      dataArray[i][j] =   ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any rule that tells you what the elements of the 9x3 array should be?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ : How can you map a 3*3 matrix with 9 values into a 9*3 matrix with 27 values? At least, explain the conversion rule or the purpose of the conversion. At least, please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] input = {{3, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 6},{8, 7, 9}};

        int[][] output = new int[9][3];

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < input[i].length; ++j) {
                output[3*i+j][0] = i;
                output[3*i+j][1] = j;
                output[3*i+j][2] = input[i][j];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < output.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < output[i].length; ++j) {
                System.out.print(output[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

This will fill your array the way you want it to be. The output is:

0 0 3

0 1 2

0 2 1

1 0 4

1 1 5

1 2 6

2 0 8

2 1 7

2 2 9

Comment: Thanks its meeting my requirement.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It would be nice if you could mark this answer as a correct and helpful answer.